# Good ebook or website links to implement ESB

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-2013

I want to implement ESB in biztalk server 2013.
Please provide me with some good website links or suggest any book for the same.

Answer (score 1):

First, what do you mean by "ESB"?

BizTalk is pretty much and ESB out of the box.

If you mean the ESB Toolkit, first, go through all the tutorials and examples so you fully understand what it does, then you can decide if it's useful.

I would not implement anything 'just because'.  There has to be a specific benefit.